# Too many open file with high limits

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, ulimit

With Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Linux 5.3.0-62-generic), I have very often "Too many open files" error.
For example, I have to close web browser to use / build / compile with Android Studio.

Hardware configuration :

- Processor Intel Core i7-5820K (6 cores / 12 virtual cores)
- 32 Go RAM
- Dual boot Ubuntu / Windows 7
- System on SSD / Ext4 part, Data on HDD / NTFS part (shared win/lin)

Configuration and system state :

```
$ ulimit -a

core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 127862
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 4096
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 500000
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

```
$ lsof | wc -l

194775
```

```
$ cat /etc/security/limits.conf

# [... commented lines ]

*               soft     nofile         500000
*               hard     nofile         500000
*               soft     nproc          500000
*               hard     nproc          500000

root            soft     nofile         500000
root            hard     nofile         500000
root            soft     nproc          500000
root            hard     nproc          500000


# End of file
```

And, for PID 3353 (Java / Android Studio)

```
$ lsof -p 3353 | wc -l

875
```

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr

14144   0   2097152
```

I don't understand why I have this error ?! ;-(

Please help

What is limit between `ulimit -n` and /etc/security/limits.conf ?

In /etc/security/limits.conf, limit is 500000 for all users.

With `ulimit -n`, limit is 4096

And `ulimit -n X` returns an error if X > 4096 :

```
ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 0):

You see this error because the open file limit is clearly exceeded.

If you look at the output of the command

lsof | grep -F ' REG '|wc -l

you'll see how many regular files are open.
This number is definitely more than the 4096 you have in your limits.

It is also very important to understand for which user you are getting this error, because in linux limits are set not only for the whole system, but also for individual users.

To solve this problem, once you have identified the culprit, you should increase the limits for the specific user and/or system as a whole.

In /etc/security/limits.conf you should write soft and hard limit
username soft nofile 799972
username hard nofile 1048576
where username is your user name

after than you should relogin to OS or, wich better, reboot computer.

Comment: Thanks.

How increase limit ?

In file /etc/security/limits.conf,  the limit is 500.000 for all users (use * char)...

And command "ulimit -n X" returns, if X > 4096, "ulimit open files cannot modify limit operation not permitted"